# Graphql get single object property of nested query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, graphql

The query looks like this:

```
query filterSomething(, , ) {
filterSomething(, , ) {
  items {
    id
    address
    name
    ipAddress
    details
    equipment {
      name
    }
  }
}
}
```

I cut out all the non-important parts. Basically the details field is an object that has a its own values associated with it. When I try doing `details { telephone}`. It gives me an error(telephone is an object property of details). How can I get that single property? Also if possible rename that value when calling the query.

Comment: *..has a its own values associated with it*. We don't know the exact structure. If it's an object then you also have to specify the fields that you want to return from that object. That is, if your schema is defined in that way. Include your schema so we know what the possibilities are.

Comment: I want to get the telephone property in the details object @EmielZuurbier

Comment: It matters what value `telephone` is. If it's an object then you should nest your query even further and specify what fields of `telephone` you need. This is why it helps for us to know how your structure is built.

Comment: Its a string but can also be null @EmielZuurbier